# Sensitiviy and Resolution in Windowing Functions

Tags: window-functions, resolution, window

When I read the  article [Windowing Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function), there are two terms that are does not understanding them well, sensitiviy and resolution.

I looked for this two terms on the web, And I conclude that sensitivity are how much you can distinguish the components of the signal, and resolution how many components you can have for a signal. Is that correct?

If my above conclusion was correct I see that the more resolution the more components I have, yields less distinguishing of that components, which means the more resolution the less sensitivity, does that also is correct? Also, does the overlpping windows is a solution for the little resolution that some windows has, for example hanning window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I object to the Wiki author's use of the words "resolution" and "sensitivity." Those words are vague and the author does not define or explain them in any meaningful way. If I was forced to use the author's poor terminology I'd say, "A fine-resolution window is a window having a narrow main lobe. (And windows whose main lobe widths are narrow have high-level sidelobes.) A window with good sensitivity is a window with low-level sidelobes. (And windows with low-level sidelobes have wider main lobes.)

I do not understand the 2nd and 3rd paragraphs of your question.

A window with a narrow main lobe improves your ability to distinguish (recognize, discriminate), in the frequency domain, two closely spaced spectral sinusoids.  A window with low sidelobe levels improves your ability to detect, in the frequency domain, a low-level sine wave that is close in frequency to a high-level sinusoid.